# Using subprocess to save image in paint

Tags: python, subprocess, paint

I need to change image compress method from PackBits to LZW, the simplest way is to open it in paint, save and close paint. I know how to open image

```
path_to_paint = 'C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe'
path_to_file = 'C:\\Users\XXX\\Desktop\\image.jpg'

subprocess.call([path_to_paint, path_to_file])
```

is there a way to save it and close paint using subprocess?
I need to do it on 100+ images.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There might be a better way, but you can always just send keystrokes with something like [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui). The hassle may be no less than finding the right utility to perform the conversion programmatically.

Comment: You'd be far better off finding a utility designed for such a task without needing coding.  Irfanview comes to mind but I'm sure there are others.